# GeckoFX-45 Execute JavaScript function

Tags: geckofx

What different between calls Navigate and AutoJSContext?

I try to use both but works only first way.

HTML Page

```
  <script src="shumway/shuobject.js"></script>
  <script>
     var swf;
    // Create/embed SWF movie.
    shuobject.embedSWF('ExampleFla.swf', 'mainSWF', 800, 512, '9,0,10', null, {}, {}, {}, function (e) {
        swf = document.getElementById("mainSWF");
    });

  function Mess(){
    var swf1 = document.getElementById("mainSWF");
    swf1.setFlashVars("VarText1=1"); // It's External Interface with Flash  and   if it's string comments AutoJSContext also will work  
    alert("Hello");
  }
```

C#

```
// It's OK
geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:Mess()"); 
// it doesn't work An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Geckofx-Core.dll
using (AutoJSContext java = new AutoJSContext(geckoWebBrowser1.Window))
        {
            java.EvaluateScript("javascript:Mess(); ", (nsISupports)geckoWebBrowser1.Window.DomWindow, out outString);
        }
```

Comment: have u solved it out @askeet?

Comment: Unfortunately, It was ages ago and now I don't  use GeckoFX in my projects. Also I see a function Navigate() to work here. And you can see the same problem https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0/issues/37/what-replaces-autojscontext

Comment: sorry then, i doesn't mean to disturb you. But what's the alternative if we dont use geckofx?

Comment: I've used a standard component C# System.Windows.Form.WebBrowser who uses the Internet Explorer. For example, I have project https://github.com/askeet/SwiffyToNet  where you can see what I mean. The reason why I tried to use GeckoFX was https://github.com/mozilla/shumway but now Flash has died